# Comparing server log dates in PHP

Tags: php, date

I'm looking to write a simple program that will tell me the last time a search engine visited any page on my site by looking at the server logs.

For example I may have:

```
$date1 = 27/Jan/2013:19:17:12 -0700
$date2 = 27/Feb/2013:19:17:12 - 0700
```

I want to know that the last time was $date2 - how do I make PHP understand the date format? Do I first need to convert that into a format that PHP understands?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Craig

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and compare timestamps

```
$date1 = '27/Jan/2013:19:17:12 - 0700';
$date2 = '27/Feb/2013:19:17:12 - 0700';
if(strtotime($date1) > strtotime($date2))
    echo $date1;
else
    echo $date2;

// outputs 27/Feb/2013:19:17:12 - 0700
```

Answer (score 1):

strtotime() will do your purpose ..
It will convert the date in string to timestamp and then uou can do the comparison.

```
<?php

$date1 = '27/Jan/2013:19:17:12 - 0700';
$date2 = '27/Feb/2013:19:17:12 - 0700';
if(strtotime($date1) > strtotime($date2))
 echo "$date1 is after $date2";
else
 echo "$date2 is after $date1";
```

Comment: Trying the example above using strtotime I get the following message:Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.

Comment: @Craig your php version is 5.3+ and you need to set default timezone in your php.ini, or using htaccess file

Comment: @Craig or you can use date_default_timezone_set('your timezone');